# Complex enumeration

Tags: c#

I have 3 lists in `List<List<decimal>>` what I'm trying to do is fill the first list with the values of other lists ONLY in case we can reach an even number across the whole list (3.2 in this case) and then delete the other lists. I am trying to build a method to do this with other numbers of lists and other values automatically, I have tried various loops with Sum() Average() and so on, usually end up with brainfarts.

```
{
  "test1": [
    2.5,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    2.5,
    0.0
  ]
}
{
  "test1": [
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.7,
    0.0
  ]
}
{
  "test1": [
    0.7,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code you have so far

Comment: What do you mean, "reach an even number?"  Where does the value 3.2 come from?

Comment: 3.2 = 2.5 + 0.7 in the first item and 8th item